# Чем лучше профилировать Ruby on Rails приложение?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, профилирование

По умолчанию Ruby on Rails в логах выдает время, затраченное на обращение к базе данных и генерацию View-представления

```
(Views: 284.3ms | ActiveRecord: 112.1ms)
```

Дополнительно выводится время генерации каждого SQL-запроса и структура времени ActiveRecord понятна, а как можно расшифровать структуру времени генерации предсталений (Views)?

Comment: Что-то очень сильно тормозит приложение?

Comment: В продакшене, где все кэшировано - все хорошо, а локально на фоне общей нагрузки, да, бывает подтормаживает, Views доходит до 14 секунд, хотелось бы посмотреть на что тратится время.

Comment: не, такое подтормаживание  только в разработке, обычно ruby-prof-ом чинят это =)

Comment: Интересно, спасибо, требуется дополнительное окружение под профилирование, надо будет поковырять. А почему не оформите ответ? С вашего позволения я размещу то, что сам нарыл за эти три дня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для профилирования можно использовать гем rack-mini-profiler в связке с гемом flamegraph, который графически представляет результаты профилирования. Подготовить приложение можно следующим образом. В Gemfile в development окружение помещаем оба гема, которые мы собираемся использовать

```
group :development do
  ...
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', require: false
  gem 'flamegraph'
  ...
end
```

Далее создаем файл инициализации config/initializers/rack_profiler.rb со следующим содержимым

```
if Rails.env == 'development'
  require 'rack-mini-profiler'

  Rack::MiniProfilerRails.initialize!(Rails.application)
end
```

Запускаем приложение и получаем результаты на любой интересующей нас странице, добавив к адресу GET-параметр ?pp=flamegraph. В результате будет выведена графическая карта с гемами, где рельсовое приложение приводит максимальное количество времени и стек вызовов методов. Наведение мышью на линии в стеке, приводит к выводу пути к файлу и методу, который ответственен за данный участок стека.

[image: Графическое представление стека вызовов в Rails-приложении]

Помимо этого можно воспользоваться средствами гема `ActiveSupport`, который входит в состав Ruby on Rails. В самом простом варианте можно использовать класс `Benchmark`, позволяющий измерить время выполнения той или иной операции:

```
>> Benchmark.ms { Post.order(created_at: :desc).limit(10) }
=> 0.134
```

Если воспользоваться методом `benchmark`, то для операции, помещенной в блок

```
collection = benchmark 'Exctracting posts collection', level: :debug do
  Post.order(created_at: :desc).limit(10)
end
```

можно добиться вывода отчета о времени выполнения операции в логи в стандартном для Rails виде:

```
...
Exctracting posts collection (134.0ms)
...
```